# Python - read in docx maintaining bullet points

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to parse a docx document to grab the references from using a regex.

I'm currently using  Python-docx, which does not preserve these:

The lines in the docx are along the lines of:

> [1] A. Calderón, M. Ruiz, Coverage of ISO/IEC 12207 software lifecycle process by a sim-ulation-based serious game, in: Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Process Improvement and Capability dEtermination (SPICE), Dublin, Ireland, 2016, pp. 59–70.
> [2] M. Kosa, M. Yilmaz, R. O’Connor, P. Clarke, Software engineering education and games: a systematic literature review, J. Universal Comput. Sci. 22 (12) (2016) 1558–1574.
> [3] C. Abt, Serious Games, University Press of America, Lanhan, MD, 2002.
> [4] A. Heredia, R. Colomo-Palacios, A. Amescua-Seco, A systematic mapping study on software process education, in: Proceedings of the 1st International Workshop on Software Process Education, Training and Professionalism (SPETP), 2015, pp. 7–17.
> [5] V. Garousi, M. Felderer, M. Mäntylä, The need for multivocal literature reviews in software engineering: complementing systematic literature reviews with grey litera-ture, Proceeding of the 20th International Conference on Evaluation and Assessment in Software Engineering (EASE), ACM, 2016 Article n. 26.
> [6] B. Kitchenham, S. Charters, Guidelines For Performing Systematic Literature Re-views in Software Engineering, Keele University and Durham University Joint Re-port, 2007.

However, when I parse it with python-docx, I get the following output:

> A. Calderón, M. Ruiz, Coverage of ISO/IEC 12207 software lifecycle process by a sim-ulation-based serious game, in: Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Process Improvement and Capability dEtermination (SPICE), Dublin, Ireland, 2016, pp. 59–70.
> M. Kosa, M. Yilmaz, R. O’Connor, P. Clarke, Software engineering education and games: a systematic literature review, J. Universal Comput. Sci. 22 (12) (2016) 1558–1574.
> C. Abt, Serious Games, University Press of America, Lanhan, MD, 2002.
> A. Heredia, R. Colomo-Palacios, A. Amescua-Seco, A systematic mapping study on software process education, in: Proceedings of the 1st International Workshop on Software Process Education, Training and Professionalism (SPETP), 2015, pp. 7–17.
> V. Garousi, M. Felderer, M. Mäntylä, The need for multivocal literature reviews in software engineering: complementing systematic literature reviews with grey litera-ture, Proceeding of the 20th International Conference on Evaluation and Assessment in Software Engineering (EASE), ACM, 2016 Article n. 26.
> B. Kitchenham, S. Charters, Guidelines For Performing Systematic Literature Re-views in Software Engineering, Keele University and Durham University Joint Re-port, 2007.

I inherited a project which parses documents and then uses a regex to extract citations. I'm trying to improve the functionality and expand it to also allow docx, and achieving the above would mean I wouldn't have to try and figure out a new regex (since a citation isn't uniform, the previous developer checked for lines beginning with the [number], and it would be a great help to continue doing this.

> [\d*] (..[^[]*, )([^[]*), (?:([^[]*))

Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Are you going to get citation with [num] head of lines?

Comment: Hi, so the intent is simply to just extract all citations within the reference section of the document. The regex looks for "[number]" and then text that follows. 

I've got a makeshift solution where I manually wrote citations like "[1] A. Calderón, M. Ruiz, Coverage of ISO/IEC 12207 software lifecycle process by a sim-ulation-based serious game, in: Proceedings of the 16th International Conference on Process Improvement and Capability dEtermination (SPICE), Dublin, Ireland, 2016, pp. 59–70." rather than it being a bullet point list, and it successfully processes it.

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'\[\d*\].*', s)`, while `s = "[1] ...... [2]....". This returns a list of strings which start with [num]. Note \ is required to escape [, ].

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding - I think it is a limitation with the library as it does not seem to pick up the bullet points. The code works, such as with your method, when I create a test document where I manually write in [1]... [2]... and do not use the bullet point function of Word - so I will just have to make do with the limitations of the library!